# Swift Protocol - Property type subclass

Tags: ios, swift, syntax, protocols

I'm defining a protocol called `PanelController` in which I'd like to store a `PanelView`. `PanelView` itself is a subclass of `UIView` and defines the basic structure of panel. I have three different views that subclass `PanelView`: `LeftPanel`, `MidPanel`, and `RightPanel`. For each of those panels I'd like to define a `xxxPanelController` (left, mid, right) that conforms to the `PanelController` protocol.

The issue I'm running up against is in the protocol and `xxxPanelController`

```
protocol PanelController {
    var panelView: PanelView { get set }
    ...
}
```

and

```
class LeftPanelController: UIViewController, PanelController {
    var panelView = LeftPanelView()
    ...
}
```

where

```
class LeftPanelView: PanelView {
     ...
}
```

and (one last piece...)

```
class PanelView: UIView {
    ...
}
```

I get an error saying that: `LeftPanelController does not conform to protocol PanelController` for an obvious reason: `panelView` is of type `LeftPanelView` not `PanelView`. This seems really limited to me, though, because `LeftPanelView` is a subclass of `PanelView` so it should just work! But it doesn't!

Can someone explain to me why this is, and if anyone can come up with one, a possible workaround? Thanks!

Comment: It does not conform because the protocol would allow that an instance of PanelView is assigned to a property of type LeftPanelView. It should compile if the property is declared as read only in the protocol.

Comment: I assume that this has been answered before, but it is difficult for me to search for it on the phone:)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The problem is with the setter in the protocol.

Let's say you want to GET the `panelView` from `LeftPanelController`. That's fine, because `LeftPanelView` can do everything `PanelView` can do (and more).

If you want to SET the `panelView` of `LeftPanelController` though, you can give it any `PanelView`. Because you're defining the `panelView` variable as a `LeftPanelView`, the setter could sometimes fail.

To fix this, you could do the following in `LeftPanelController`:

```
var panelView: PanelView = LeftPanelView()
```

The implication of this is that you won't be able to access any methods or properties that are specific to `LeftPanelView` without casting it first. If that's not an issue, then this should fix your problem!

Comment: Do you know of a way to store the type (i.e. `LeftPanelView`) in a variable to use for casting later? (In order to decouple the view from the `PanelController` further.)

Comment: What is the use case? If you need a `LeftPanelView` object, you should store that type of object. If you have a protocol that you're using instead, I'm assuming that the specific type of object does not matter. If it does, a protocol may not be the appropriate solution.

Comment: Does the same explanation apply if `PanelView` was a protocol that they all conformed to? I'm having an issue similar to this, except that my `PanelView` is a protocol. Your explanation makes sense in the case of inheriting from a base class, but I'm struggling to understand why this wouldn't work with a protocol since all you care about is that they implement the methods as defined in the protocol.

Comment: Yes, the explanation still applies. The issue is that the controller thinks the `panelView` is a `LeftPanelView` instead of a `PanelView`. That's why the explicit declaration fixes the issue. Does that help?

Comment: The issue exists even with a get-only property.