# Swift protocol associated types and inheritance contraints

Tags: ios, swift, generics, uicollectionview, protocols

I want to build an iOS app with a `UICollectionViewController` that always have the same number of cells per row. Because I don't want my `UICollectionViewController` to deal with too much things, I've refactored my code and implemented funny things like `protocol associatedtype` and generic types. Now, my app is composed of 4 different `.swift` files.

---

#### 1. `CustomFlowLayout.swift`

`CustomFlowLayout` is a simple subclass of `UICollectionViewFlowLayout` that allows us to set its `minimumInteritemSpacing`, `minimumLineSpacing` and `sectionInset` properties with dependency injection thanks to a convenience initializer.

```
import UIKit

class CustomFlowLayout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout {

    convenience init(minimumInteritemSpacing: CGFloat = 0,
                     minimumLineSpacing: CGFloat = 0,
                     sectionInset: UIEdgeInsets = .zero) {
        self.init()
        self.minimumInteritemSpacing = minimumInteritemSpacing
        self.minimumLineSpacing = minimumLineSpacing
        self.sectionInset = sectionInset
    }

    override init() {
        super.init()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

}
```

#### 2. `ColumnDataSource.swift`

`ColumnDataSource` is a subclass of `NSObject` that conforms to `UICollectionViewDataSource`, `UICollectionViewDelegate` and `UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout`. Its implements `collectionView(_:layout:sizeForItemAt:)` in order to display the correct number of `UICollectionViewCell`s per row. Also note that `ColumnDataSource` is a generic class that requires us to pass it a type parameter at initialization.

```
import UIKit

class ColumnDataSource<FlowLayoutType: UICollectionViewFlowLayout>: NSObject, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {

    let cellsPerRow: Int

    init(cellsPerRow: Int) {
        self.cellsPerRow = cellsPerRow
        super.init()
    }

    // MARK: - UICollectionViewDataSource

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 10
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        return collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath)
    }

    // MARK: - UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        let flowLayout = collectionView.collectionViewLayout as! FlowLayoutType
        let marginsAndInsets = flowLayout.sectionInset.left + flowLayout.sectionInset.right + flowLayout.minimumInteritemSpacing * (CGFloat(cellsPerRow) - 1)
        let itemWidth = (collectionView.bounds.size.width - marginsAndInsets) / CGFloat(cellsPerRow)
        return CGSize(width: itemWidth, height: itemWidth)
    }

}
```

#### 3. `ColumnFlowLayoutable.swift`

The purpose of `ColumnFlowLayoutable` protocol is to make sure that any class that conforms to it has `columnDataSource` and `customFlowLayout` properties where `columnDataSource` type's type parameter matches `customFlowLayout` type.

```
import UIKit

protocol ColumnFlowLayoutable {

    associatedtype FlowLayoutType: UICollectionViewFlowLayout
    var columnDataSource: ColumnDataSource<FlowLayoutType> { get }
    var customFlowLayout: FlowLayoutType { get }

}
```

#### 4. `CollectionViewController.swift`

`CollectionViewController` is a subclass of `UICollectionViewController` that conforms to `ColumnFlowLayoutable` protocol. It also implement `viewWillTransition(to:with:)` in order to deal with container size changes.

```
import UIKit

class CollectionViewController: UICollectionViewController, ColumnFlowLayoutable {

    let columnDataSource = ColumnDataSource<CustomFlowLayout>(cellsPerRow: 2)
    let customFlowLayout = {
        CustomFlowLayout(minimumInteritemSpacing: $0, minimumLineSpacing: $0, sectionInset: UIEdgeInsets(top: $0, left: $0, bottom: $0, right: $0))
    }(10)

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        collectionView?.collectionViewLayout = customFlowLayout
        collectionView?.dataSource = columnDataSource
        collectionView?.delegate = columnDataSource
    }

    override func viewWillTransition(to size: CGSize, with coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {
        super.viewWillTransition(to: size, with: coordinator)
        collectionView?.collectionViewLayout.invalidateLayout()
    }

}
```

The complete project can be found at this Github repo: [CollectionViewColumnsProtocol](https://github.com/imanoupetit/CollectionViewColumnsProtocol).

---

This code works fine. I can use it with subclasses of `CustomFlowLayout` and it still works. **However, I cannot use it with subclasses of `ColumnDataSource`**.

If I try to build the project by using a subclass of `ColumnDataSource` (e.g `class SubColumnDataSource: ColumnDataSource<CustomFlowLayout>`) in `CollectionViewController`, Xcode throws the following build time error message:

> Type 'CollectionViewController' does not conform to protocol 'ColumnFlowLayoutable'

What would I have to change in `ColumnFlowLayoutable` protocol in order to allow `CollectionViewController` to work with subclasses of `ColumnDataSource`?

Comment: This topic is related to [Swift Protocol - Property type subclass](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32231420/swift-protocol-property-type-subclass).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a DataSource protocol with an associated type for your layout type:

```
protocol ColumnDataSourceProtocol: UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {
    associatedtype Layout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout
}
```

Make your DataSource base class conform to this protocol. You may need to add a `typealias` to specify the associatedtype if the compiler cannot infer it:

```
class ColumnDataSource<FlowLayoutType: UICollectionViewFlowLayout>: NSObject, ColumnDataSourceProtocol {

    typealias Layout = FlowLayoutType

    // the rest stays the same
}
```

Adapt `ColumnFlowLayoutable` to associate the data source type instead of the layout type. Constraining it to the `ColumnDataSourceProtocol` lets you access its associated `Layout` type:

```
protocol ColumnFlowLayoutable {

    associatedtype DataSource: ColumnDataSourceProtocol

    var columnDataSource: DataSource { get }
    var customFlowLayout: DataSource.Layout { get }
}
```

Now you can subclass `ColumnDataSource`:

```
class DataSource: ColumnDataSource<CustomFlowLayout> { /* ... */ }
```

Comment: Thanks. I had missed that point: protocols can inherit from other protocols.

Comment: Thanks a lot, your answer save my night from the doc diving)