# Why can't a get-only property requirement in a protocol be satisfied by a property which conforms?

Tags: swift, swift-protocols

Why does the following code produce an error?

```
protocol ProtocolA {
    var someProperty: ProtocolB { get }
}

protocol ProtocolB {}
class ConformsToB: ProtocolB {}

class SomeClass: ProtocolA { // Type 'SomeClass' does not conform to protocol 'ProtocolA'
    var someProperty: ConformsToB

    init(someProperty: ConformsToB) {
        self.someProperty = someProperty
    }
}
```

[The answer in this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32231991/343299) makes sense.  However, in my example, the property is get-only.  Why shouldn't this work?  Is it a shortcoming of Swift, or is there some reason this makes sense?

Comment: Thanks for the links. That's unfortunate, but good to know!

Comment: If you want this behavior, in `ProtocolA` you should have `associatedtype T: ProtocolB` and then declare `var someProperty: T { get }`

Comment: That would work as a workaround in the meantime until it's (hopefully) fixed, but I'm really hesitant to add an associated type, as that would bubble that knowledge to the rest of the object graph, which gets out of control quickly.

Comment: As of Swiftt 5.1 you can use opaque return types in conjunctioni with associated types to avoid bubbling them through the object graph.

Comment: @IliasKarim can you add that as an Answer?

Comment: @pkamb I added an answer.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

There's no real reason why this shouldn't be possible, a read-only property requirement *can* be covariant, as returning a `ConformsToB` instance from a property typed as `ProtocolB` is perfectly legal.

Swift just currently doesn't support it. In order to do so, the compiler would have to generate [a thunk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thunk) between the protocol witness table and conforming implementation in order to perform the necessary type-conversion(s). For example, a `ConformsToB` instance would need to be *boxed* [in an existential container](https://youtu.be/9By9KLs51Dc?t=24m30s) in order to be typed as `ProtocolB` (and there's no way the caller can do this, as it might not know anything about the implementation being called).

But again, there's no reason why the compiler shouldn't be able to do this. There are multiple bug reports open over this, [this one](https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-1950) which is specific to read-only property requirements, and [this general one](https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-522), in which Slava Pestov, a member of the Swift team, says:

> [...] we want protocol witnesses and method overrides in every case where a function conversion is allowed

So it definitely looks like something the Swift team are looking to implement in a future version of the language.

In the mean time however, as [@BallpointBen says](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42561685/why-cant-a-get-only-property-requirement-in-a-protocol-be-satisfied-by-a-proper#comment72258030_42561685), one workaround is to use an `associatedtype`:

```
protocol ProtocolA {
    // allow the conforming type to satisfy this with a concrete type
    // that conforms to ProtocolB.
    associatedtype SomeProperty : ProtocolB
    var someProperty: SomeProperty { get }
}

protocol ProtocolB {}
class ConformsToB: ProtocolB {}

class SomeClass: ProtocolA {

    // implicitly satisfy the associatedtype with ConformsToB.
    var someProperty: ConformsToB

    init(someProperty: ConformsToB) {
        self.someProperty = someProperty
    }
}
```

But this is quite unsatisfactory, as it means that `ProtocolA` is no longer usable as a type (because it has `associatedtype` requirements). It also changes what the protocol says. Originally it said that `someProperty` could return *anything* that conformed to `ProtocolB` – now it says that an implementation of `someProperty` deals with just one *specific* concrete type that conforms to `ProtocolB`.

Another workaround is just to define a dummy property in order to satisfy the protocol requirement:

```
protocol ProtocolA {
    var someProperty: ProtocolB { get }
}

protocol ProtocolB {}
class ConformsToB: ProtocolB {}

class SomeClass: ProtocolA {

    // dummy property to satisfy protocol conformance.
    var someProperty: ProtocolB {
        return actualSomeProperty
    }

    // the *actual* implementation of someProperty.
    var actualSomeProperty: ConformsToB

    init(someProperty: ConformsToB) {
        self.actualSomeProperty = someProperty
    }
}
```

Here we're essentially writing the thunk *for* the compiler – but it's also not particularly nice as it adds a needless property to the API.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer @Hamish.  I've already been doing what you've suggested (the computed property wrapper), but I agree, it's unfortunate to have to add another property.

Comment: There is at least 1 potential problem with covariance of read-only protocol properties. Here: https://forums.swift.org/t/should-allow-covariance-of-get-only-protocol-property-requirements/27937/10

Comment: The youtube link provided in this answer is down due to copyright issues!

Answer (score 2):

In addition to Harmish's great response, if you want to keep using the same property name on both `SomeClass` and `ProtocolA`, you can do

```
protocol ProtocolB {}

protocol ProtocolA {
    var _someProperty_protocolA: ProtocolB { get }
}

extension ProtocolA {
    var someProperty: ProtocolB {
        return _someProperty_protocolA
    }
}

class ConformsToB: ProtocolB {}

class SomeClass: ProtocolA {


    // the *actual* implementation of someProperty.
    var _someProperty: ConformsToB

    var someProperty: ConformsToB {
      // You can't expose someProperty directly as
      // (SomeClass() as ProtocolA).someProperty would
      // point to the getter in ProtocolA and loop
      return _someProperty
    }

    // dummy property to satisfy protocol conformance.
    var _someProperty_protocolA: ProtocolB {
        return someProperty
    }

    init(someProperty: ConformsToB) {
        self.someProperty = someProperty
    }
}

let foo = SomeClass(someProperty: ConformsToB())
// foo.someProperty is a ConformsToB
// (foo as ProtocolA).someProperty is a ProtocolB
```

This can be useful when you are conforming to another protocol `ProtocolA2` that would originally also have constraint on `someProperty` as well, or when you want to hide your hack around swift limitations.

I'm now curious to know why Swift is not doing this for me directly.

Answer (score 1):

Beginning in Swift 5.1, you can use opaque return types to reference a protocol that references another protocol, so long as you also use associatedtypes to do so.

Not only does it work for readonly "get" properties, but also readwrite properties. For example,

```
protocol ProtocolA {
  associatedtype T: ProtocolB
  var someProperty: T { get }
  var x: Int { get set }
}

protocol ProtocolB {
  var x: Int { get set }
}

struct ConformsToB: ProtocolB {
  var x: Int
}

class SomeClass: ProtocolA {
  var someProperty: ConformsToB

  init(someProperty: ConformsToB) {
    self.someProperty = someProperty
  }

  var x: Int {
    get {
      someProperty.x
    }
    set {
      someProperty.x = newValue
    }
  }
}

var protocolA: some ProtocolA = SomeClass(someProperty: ConformsToB(x: 1))

print(protocolA.x) // 1
protocolA.x = 2
print(protocolA.x) // 2
```