# support var!? in protocol

Tags: swift, swift-protocols

i have 3 classes

```
class A {
    var uid: Int64!
    var countryCode: String? // <-- Attention 
}

class B {
    var uid: Int64!
    var countryCode: String! // <-- Attention
}

class C {
    var uid: Int64!
    var countryCode: String = "AA" // <-- Attention
}
```

witch var for example `countryCode` as `String?`, `String!`
, `String`

and i create protocol, witch var as `String?` (As the weakest type to which you can bring all the others)

```
protocol FullCode {
    var uid: Int64! { get }
    var countryCode: String? { get } // <-- How to describe a variable for all (`T`, `T!`, `T?`) types?
}

extension FullCode {
    var fullCode: String? { return "specificCode"}
}
```

bat if i added it to  my classes

```
extension A : FullCode {}
extension B : FullCode {}
extension C : FullCode {}
```

i get error for classes B & C.

How can use one protocol for these types?

Comment: Related: [Why can't a get-only property requirement in a protocol be satisfied by a property which conforms?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/42561685/2976878). There's no real reason why your code shouldn't work, as both `String!` and `String` are convertible to `String?`. The compiler just doesn't support it yet.

Answer (score 1):

You can't make either `B` or `C` conform to `FullCode`, because the types for `countryCode` are incompatible.

You can't make this work by changing the type of `FullCode.countryCode`, because there is no common supertype for `String`, `String!`, and `String?`.

You'll need to change `FullCode` to declare some other property. Example:

```
protocol FullCode {
    var uid: Int64! { get }
    var optionalCountryCode: String? { get }
}

extension A : FullCode {
    var optionalCountryCode: String? { return countryCode }
}

extension B : FullCode {
    var optionalCountryCode: String? { return countryCode }
}

extension C : FullCode {
    var optionalCountryCode: String? { return countryCode }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I know this way, it works, but it burdens the code very much. Maybe there is something more beautiful and simple?

Comment: I don't see what you can do besides changing `B.countryCode` and `C.countryCode` to `String?`.

Comment: `String?` is just shorthand for `Optional<String>` which isn't the same thing as `String` so they can't be made to match.