# Swift: conforming to properties in protocol?

Tags: swift, swift-protocols, gameplay-kit

How to confirm to protocols that declares properties of other protocols in Swift?

There is a protocol `GKGameModel` in which its implementers need to have a properties conforming to a protocol

```
public protocol GKGameModel {
    // ...
    public var players: [GKGameModelPlayer]? { get }
    public var activePlayer: GKGameModelPlayer? { get }
    // ...

}

public protocol GKGameModelPlayer {
    // ...
}
```

Now, suppose I have a class `Player` and `GameModel` that conforms to the above protocols

```
class Player : NSObject, GKGameModelPlayer  {
    //...
}


class GameModel : NSObject, GKGameModel  {
    //...
    public var players: [Player]? 
    public var activePlayer: Player?
}
```

Now the above code doesn't compile and the error messages (among others) were:

```
protocol requires property 'activePlayer' with type 'GKGameModelPlayer?'; do you want to add a stub?
candidate has non-matching type 'Player?'
```

However the `Player` class conforms to protocol `GKGameModelPlayer`, hence it should confirm just fine. How can I get this to compile?

Strangely Objective-C deals with this just fine – take a look at the [FourInARow](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/samplecode/FourInARow/Introduction/Intro.html) example code which does something like this.

Comment: Related (dupe?): [Why can't a get-only property requirement in a protocol be satisfied by a property which conforms?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/42561685/2976878). There's no real reason why this shouldn't be possible, as a `[Player]?` is convertible to a `[GKGameModelPlayer]?` and a `Player?` is convertible to a `GKGameModelPlayer?` – the compiler just doesn't support it yet.

Answer (score 0):

The protocol requires that the properties be typed exactly as shown. In other words, an array of `GKGameModelPlayer`s and a single optional `GKGameModelPlayer?`.  If your `Player` type conforms to the protocol, then an array of `Player`s can be passed to the protocol property if casted / typed as `[GKGameModelPlayer]`.

But the requirement here is not, for example, an `activePlayer` property that has a type that *conforms* to `GKGameModelPlayer`, but rather an `activePlayer` property that references an instance that it typed as / cast as a `GKGameModelPlayer`.

I.e. this would fix the error:

```
class GameModel : NSObject, GKGameModel  {
    //...
    public var players: [GKGameModelPlayer]? 
    public var activePlayer: GKGameModelPlayer?
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`players` and `activePlayer` property has a type that *conforms* to `GKGameModelPlayer`. So just change it to `GKGameModelPlayer` type instead of `Player`

```
class GameModel : NSObject, GKGameModel  {
    //...
    public var players: [GKGameModelPlayer]? 
    public var activePlayer: GKGameModelPlayer?
}
```