# Swift protocol extension for DTO model

Tags: swift, protocols

I have created DTOUser, DTOLocation struct model and
defined User, Location protocol like below

```
struct DTOUser {
    var name: String
    var age: Int
    var location: DTOLocation
}

struct DTOLocation {
    var city: String
    var country: String
}

protocol User {
    var name: String { get }
    var age: Int { get }
    var location: Location { get }
}

protocol Location {
    var city: String { get }
    var country: String { get }
}
```

and extend DTOLocation and DTOUser but DTOUser can't extend User protocol 
because User did not defined Location type named location variable

```
extension DTOLocation: Location {}

extension DTOUser: User {} << ERROR HERE 
// type 'DTOUser' does not conform to protocol 'User'
```

I want to extend DTOUser model extend User protocol
how can i do it? any idea?

Comment: Compare (dupe?): [Why can't a get-only property requirement in a protocol be satisfied by a property which conforms?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/42561685/2976878)

Comment: @Hamish yes it was dupe https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-522 already reported bugs

Comment: DTOUser has location as DTOLocation, and User protocol location is Location Type