# Swift 'does not conform to protocol' when returning concrete type to satisfy protocol

Tags: swift, protocols

Can anybody elaborate why Swift is unhappy with the following code? The Swift compiler is complaining that the class GameBoard does not conform to the protocol. This would be allowed in Java.

```
protocol PGameBoard {
    func buildSettlement(point: Point, playerId: Player.Id) -> PGameBoard
}

class GameBoard: PGameBoard {
    var dummy: String

    init(dummy: String) {
        self.dummy = dummy
    }

    public func buildSettlement(point: Point, playerId: Player.Id) -> GameBoard {
        return GameBoard(dummy: "settlement is built")
    }
}
```

I appreciate that if I return a PGameBoard from the concrete implementation it fixes the issue, however In my experience with Java I have found it better to refer to the interface within the interface code and the concrete class within the implementation code. Sometimes I do want to call GameBoard.buildSettlement() and return a GameBoard rather than a PGameBoard.

Related to Hamish's helpful reply - I have found out that the formal description of the situation is that of requiring a return type that is covariant of the protocol return type. As of Swift 3.0 this behaviour is not implemented. However, Chris Lattner on swift-evolution suggested that this is a bug and in all cases covariant return types should be allowed.

Comment: Compare [Why can't a get-only property requirement in a protocol be satisfied by a property which conforms?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42561685/2976878) (basically a dupe). In short, there's no real reason why it isn't possible; Swift just doesn't support it yet.

Comment: It's complaining because you didn't implement EXACTLY the function that you defined in the protocol. Your attempt at conformance returns a `GameBoard` but your protocol requires you to return a `PGameBoard`.