# Conforming to protocol using var declared with protocol composition

Tags: swift

Is something like this possible in Swift?

```
protocol SpeaksGerman {
    func speakGerman()
}

protocol SpeaksFrench {
    func speakFrench()
}

protocol HasGermanSpeaker {
    var speaker: SpeaksGerman! {get}
}

protocol HasFrenchSpeaker {
    var speaker: SpeaksFrench! {get}
}

class IHaveAPolyglotSpeaker: HasGermanSpeaker {
    var speaker: (SpeaksGerman & SpeaksFrench)!
}
```

Since `var speaker` is declared as conforming to both `SpeaksGerman` and `SpeaksFrench` I'd expect `IHaveAPolyglotSpeaker` to conform to any of the `HasGermanSpeaker` or `HasFrenchSpeaker` protocols.

Comment: _I'd expect IHaveAPolyglotSpeaker to conform to any of the HasGermanSpeaker or HasFrenchSpeaker protocols._ Absolutely it would not. `HasGermanSpeaker` is not inherited by `SpeaksGerman` so there is no way to know `IHaveAPolyglotSpeaker.speaker` would conform to `HasGermanSpeaker` or `HasFrenchSpeaker`. You need to rethink your design.

Comment: hmm, `HasGermanSpeaker` requires a property `speaker` of type `SpeaksGerman`. `IHaveAPolyglotSpeaker` has a a property `speaker` of type `SpeaksGerman`. I'm not sure what inheritance has to do with it.

Comment: Doesn't matter. You still don't know if `IHaveAPolyglotSpeaker.speaker` conforms to `HasGermanSpeaker`.

Comment: @OzgurVatansever `IHaveAPolyglotSpeaker.speaker` conforms to `SpeaksGerman`, it doesn't have to conform to `HasGermanSpeaker`

Comment: but not to `HasGermanSpeaker` which is what you want it to. Your design is definitely flawed. Maybe you should explain us what you really want to achieve.

Comment: Compare https://stackoverflow.com/q/42561685/2976878 – in short, there's no real reason why this isn't possible; it just isn't supported yet.

Comment: @Hamish hmm, it looks similar example but I'm not sure I get it entirely

Comment: @OzgurVatansever `IHaveAPolyglotSpeaker` has a `speaker` var with the type `SpeaksGerman`, which is exactly what conforming to `HasGermanSpeaker` means. I think you're confusing the protocol that `speaker` conforms to with the one `IHaveAPolyglotSpeaker` needs to conform to.

Comment: Make your func speakGerman() and your func speakFrench() optional by putting the keywork optional in front of them and I think it will work.

Comment: @marosoaie What part exactly are you unsure about? I've closed this as a dupe for now, but am happy to re-open if you could clarify what part you're unsure about.