# How to make one protocol with a property that is another protocol, yet ensure that classes which conform to the first protocol can be restricted

Tags: ios, swift, class, protocols

Essentially, my end goal is to have one protocol `Log` which enforces that all objects which conform to it have an array of objects that conform to another protocol `[LogEvent]`.

However, the classes which conform to `Log` need to have specific types of `LogEvent`, e.g. `NumericalLogEvent`, in the `events` array, not the more general `LogEvent`.

I'm getting the error "Type 'NumericalLog' does not conform to protocol 'Log'" when I try to use the code below.

How do I ensure that everything that conforms to log has *some* events array of type LogEvent, yet leave it open as to exactly which type that is?

```
protocol Log {
    var events: [LogEvent] { get set } // Want to enforce events here
}

protocol LogEvent {
    timeStamp: Date { get set }
}

struct NumericalLogEvent: LogEvent {
    timeStamp: Date
    value: Float
}

class NumericalLog: Log {
    var events: [NumericalLogEvent]

    // But getting error here when trying to use more specific type. 
}
```

Comment: Compare https://stackoverflow.com/q/42561685/2976878. Sounds like you want an `associatedtype` here.

Answer (score 1):

**Got it!**

The trick is to set an `associatedtype` (the equivalent of a generic for protocols) and then to set this as the type in `events`.

```
protocol Log {
    associatedtype Event: LogEvent

    var events: [Event] { get set }
}
```