# Swift protocol with a member typed as another protocol

Tags: swift, generics, protocols, associated-types

I'm experimenting with Swift protocols, and I've run into something funny. There are lots of workarounds, but can anyone explain the error below?

```
protocol UserRenderable {
    var name : String { get }
}

protocol PostRenderable {
    var title: String { get }
    var author: UserRenderable { get }
}

struct User {
    let id: String
    let name : String
}

struct Post {
    let id: String
    let title: String
    let author: User
}

extension User : UserRenderable {}

extension Post: PostRenderable {}
```

The above code (drop it in a playground, or whatever) will throw a compilation error:

> protocol requires property 'author' with type 'UserRenderable'; do you want to add a stub?
>      var author: UserRenderable { get }

What's the reason for this?

Answer (score 0):

The best solution for this isn't with associated types. It looks like there's a neater option (from [the answer to another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42561685/why-cant-a-get-only-property-requirement-in-a-protocol-be-satisfied-by-a-proper)):

> There's no real reason why this shouldn't be possible, a read-only
>   property requirement can be covariant, as returning a ConformsToB
>   instance from a property typed as ProtocolB is perfectly legal.
>
> Swift just currently doesn't support it. In order to do so, the
>   compiler would have to generate a thunk between the protocol witness
>   table and conforming implementation in order to perform the necessary
>   type-conversion(s). For example, a ConformsToB instance would need to
>   be boxed in an existential container in order to be typed as ProtocolB
>   (and there's no way the caller can do this, as it might not know
>   anything about the implementation being called).
>
> But again, there's no reason why the compiler shouldn't be able to do
>   this.

It turns out you can *trick* the compiler into doing your bidding, without writing a thunk, using good old `typelias`. This code compiles without issue:

```
protocol UserRenderable {
    var name : String { get }
}

protocol PostRenderable {
    var title: String { get }
    var author: UserRenderable { get }
}

struct User {
    let id: String
    let name : String
}

struct Post {
    let id: String
    let title: String
    let author: User
}

extension User : UserRenderable {}

extension Post: PostRenderable {
    typealias User = UserRenderable
}
```

Comment: @josh-caswell, do you happen to know *why* this works?

Answer (score -1):

Your `Post` struct has a very specific type for the `author`. The protocol specifies that something that is `PostRenderable` needs to have an author that is `UserRenderable`. While all `User`s are `UserRenderable`, not all `UserRenderable` items are `User`. Therefor, you should change the type of `author` to `UserRenderable` instead of `User`.