# Protocol variable implementing another protocol

Tags: swift, swift-protocols

I'm trying to do something like that, but then, `ParentC` doesn't conform to `Parent` because its `children` member isn't `Child` but `ChildC`

Which is weird because `ChildC` implements `Child`...

Is this a limit of Swift? Or is there is a way of doing that?

(I do not ask for an alternative solution, I want to know if **this** is possible)

```
protocol Parent: Codable {
    var children: [Child] { get }
}

protocol Child: Codable {
    var name: String { get }
}

struct ParentC: Parent {
    var children: [ChildC]
}

struct ChildC: Child {
    var name: String
}
```

Comment: Compare https://stackoverflow.com/q/42561685/2976878

Comment: @Hamish Impressive answer, I understand it's not possible, moreover, the alternative proposed in your answer would force to implement `encode` and `decode` of `Codable`, such a shame :(

Comment: You should be able to get an automatic `Codable` conformance, see for example https://gist.github.com/hamishknight/e64305a10448610a433a6077733888f1

Comment: @Hamish that's a great tweak to get it to work (option 1)! Thanks

Comment: Option 2 is more flexible. Also, @Hamish instead of `gist` link in the comments it should be answer below.

Answer (score 2):

You can workaround this variance "limitation" by making `Parent` a protocol with associated type:

```
protocol Parent: Codable {
    associatedtype ChildType: Child
    var children: [ChildType] { get }
}
```

This will impact the places you can use `Parent` though, since protocols with associated types have some restrictions on where to use them.