# Swift transitive protocol conformance

Tags: swift, protocols

Could someone explain why won't the following example compile? Am I missing something trivial?

```
protocol Coordinator {}

protocol Coordinatable {
    var coordinator: Coordinator { get set }
}

class ExampleCoordinator: Coordinator {}

class ViewController: UIViewController, Coordinatable {
    var coordinator: ExampleCoordinator!
}
```

The error is:

```
Type 'ViewController' does not conform to protocol 'Coordinatable'
```

Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Protocol variable implementing another protocol](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49554288/protocol-variable-implementing-another-protocol) (also note that you are providing an _optional_ when the protocol requires a non-optional)

Comment: It also does, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## The reason that it doesn't work

Assuming your code would work and we write additionally

```
class ExampleCoordinator2: Coordinator {}

val viewController = ViewController()
viewController.coordinator = ExampleCoordinator2()
```

The assignment to `coordinator` cannot work since `ExampleCoordinator2` is not a subclass of `ExampleCoordinator`.

So, **just considering the types** the following code should work **but the Swift compiler doesn't allow it** (this might work in the future):

```
protocol Coordinatable {
    var coordinator: Coordinator { get } // removing the `set`
}

class ViewController: UIViewController, Coordinatable {
    var coordinator: ExampleCoordinator! // still an error
}
```

---

## Possible solutions

### Using `var coordinator: Coordinator` in `ViewController`

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, Coordinatable {

    var coordinator: Coordinator

    init(coordinator: Coordinator) {
        self.coordinator = coordinator
        super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
    }

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}
```

### Using only `{ get }` in `Coordinatable`

```
protocol Coordinatable {
    var coordinator: Coordinator { get } // removing the `set`
}

class ViewController: UIViewController, Coordinatable {
    // computed property
    var coordinator: Coordinator {
        // implicit return
        exampleCoordinator
    }
    var exampleCoordinator: ExampleCoordinator!
}
```

### Using an `associatedtype` in `Coordinatable`

```
protocol Coordinatable {
    associatedtype C: Coordinator
    var coordinator: C { get set }
}

class ViewController: UIViewController, Coordinatable {
    
    var coordinator: ExampleCoordinator
    
    init(coordinator: ExampleCoordinator) {
        self.coordinator = coordinator
        super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}
```

This has however a **big disadvantage** that you cannot have a heterogenous array of type `[Coordinatable]` since `Coordinatable` has an `associatedtype`. And still, you cannot assign a value of type `ExampleCoordinator2`.

You can only write generic code over `<C: Coordinatable>`. E.g.

```
func printCoordinators<C: Coordinatable>(coordinatables: [C]) {
    
    coordinatables.forEach {
        print($0.coordinator)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace `var coordinator: ExampleCoordinator!` with `var coordinator: Coordinator`. You are trying to conform to `Coordinatable` so you have to implement it's properties.

EDIT:

```
import UIKit
protocol Coordinator {}

protocol Coordinatable {
    var coordinator: Coordinator { get set }
}

class ExampleCoordinator: Coordinator {}

class ViewController: UIViewController, Coordinatable {
    var coordinator: Coordinator

    init(coordinator: Coordinator) {
        self.coordinator = coordinator
        super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
    }

    // ignore this, it has nothing to do with the question/answer
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}

let testVC = ViewController(coordinator: ExampleCoordinator()) // works
```

Comment: But `ExampleCoordinator` implements `Coordinator`, so I am implicitly implementing the required property.

Comment: Well the protocol requires you to implement a `Coordinator` not an `ExampleCoordinator`. So do what I described above and then pass an `ExampleCoordinator` during the initialisation and set `self.coordinator` to this very `ExampleCoordinator`

Comment: I updated my answer a bit to make it more clear :) (Just paste it into a playground a play with it)