# Protocols inheritance and typing incomprehension

Tags: swift, swift-protocols

I am a bit confused. Please look at this example.

I created a VM protocol:

```
protocol VM {

}
```

And this protocol is using in my VC implementation

```
final class VC: UIViewController {
    let viewModel: VM
}
```

Now I create special new protocols

```
protocol AwesomeProtocol {

}

protocol AwesomeViewProtocol {
     var viewModel: AwesomeProtocol { get }
}
```

My idea is to expand `VM` with `Awesomeness` so:

```
protocol VM: AwesomeProtocol {

}

final class VC: UIViewController, AwesomeViewProtocol {
    let viewModel: VM
}
```

But here I met an compiler error:

> Type 'VC' does not conform to protocol 'AwesomeViewProtocol'

Despite the fact that `VM` extend `AwesomeProtocol`

Someone could explain me what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Compare https://stackoverflow.com/q/42561685/2976878

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to implement this.

```
final class VC: UIViewController, AwesomeViewProtocol {
    var viewModel: AwesomeProtocol
}
```

computed variables are close to the functions. Their signatures must be the same in a parent and child (inherited) classes/protocols.

If you need something abstracts use `assosiatedtype` and generic classes instead.

Comment: In your implementation `VC` lose access to `VM` methods. It will can use only `AwesomeProtocol` interface. According to your answer I assume that my implementation idea is not possible and the only case is to use mentioned `assosiatedtype`. Am I right?

Comment: @KamilHarasimowicz I think, yes