# The difference between an associated type and 'normal' type?

Tags: swift, protocols, swift-protocols

I have this code:

```
import UIKit

protocol ProtocolA {
    associatedtype View: ProtocolB
    var someView: View { get }
}

protocol ProtocolB { }

class MyView: UIView, ProtocolB {}

class MyClass: ProtocolA {
    var someView = MyView()
}
```

This compiles. `MyView` conforms to `ProtocolB`, and therefore is a `ProtocolB`. `MyClass` conforms to `ProtocolA` because it has a `ProtocolB` as property. So far so good.

But why is the **associated type necessary** here for the code to compile? Why does this not compile?

```
import UIKit

protocol ProtocolA {
    var someView: ProtocolB { get }
}

protocol ProtocolB { }

class MyView: UIView, ProtocolB {}

class MyClass: ProtocolA { // Error here, it doesn't conform to ProtocolA.
    var someView = MyView()
}
```

Why?! `MyView` is still a `ProtocolB` right? I can fix this by doing this:

```
var someView: ProtocolB = MyView()
```

But that's strange because `MyView` is always `ProtocolB`. I also can't access any property defined in `MyView` now.

What is the difference between two codes? It looks like they are really the same. Why does the associated type allows subclasses, why the 'normal' type doesn't?

Comment: Compare https://stackoverflow.com/q/42561685/2976878 – there's no technical reason why your second example shouldn't work.

Comment: @Hamish I think you answered every possible protocol question about Swift on SO :D

Comment: I've certainly tried my best :) Are you happy with marking this as a duplicate of that Q&A?

Comment: @Hamish yes you can close this one! Thank you for all of your efforts to this community!