# Why isn't Swift protocol conformance satisfied when type conforms to multiple protocols

Tags: swift, swift-protocols

Let's say you have the following protocols and class:

```
protocol Foo { }

protocol Bar { }

protocol Deps {
  var bar: Bar { get }
}

class FooBar: Foo, Bar { }
```

And then you define a new class with a property which conforms to both `Foo` and `Bar` protocols.

```
class Scope: Deps {
  let bar: Foo & Bar = FooBar() // ❌ does not compile
}
```

Despite it seemingly satisfying the `Deps` protocol requirement, it doesn't compile. The compiler provides this message:

```
error: type 'Scope' does not conform to protocol 'Deps'
class Scope: Deps {
      ^

Protocols_Question.playground:6:7: note: candidate has non-matching type 'Bar & Foo'
```

However, removing the second protocol conformance resolves the compilation issue:

```
class Scope: Deps {
  let bar: Bar = FooBar() // ✅ compiles
}
```

What is going on here? Intuitively it seems like `Deps` protocol conformance should be satisfied in the first example.

[Here's a Swift Playground](https://www.dropbox.com/s/n47nkzhbcv2e3wl/Protocols_Question.playground.zip?dl=0) demonstrating the problem.

Comment: `associatedtype DepsType: Bar` and then `typealias DepsType = FooBar` would make it even better. I am not sure right now about the exact reason but the solution is to use associated types.

Comment: Compare [Why can't a get-only property requirement in a protocol be satisfied by a property which conforms?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42561685/2976878) (duplicate?) – there's no real reason why this isn't possible, the compiler just doesn't handle it yet.

Answer (score 0):

It's because the Deps protocol requires the variable bar to conform to the protocol Bar. You can assign the class FooBar() (with both the Foo and Bar protocol) to the variable bar because the requirement is for bar to (at least) conform to the Bar protocol. However you cannot try to change what protocols a variable should conform to after it has been defined.

TL;DR - You can't change the type of a variable after it's been declared.