# Protocol inheritance and structs in swift

Tags: swift, struct

I want to create a `Validatable` protocol that has two properties: a `validator` and an `isAbleToProceed` boolean:

```
protocol Validatable {
    var validator: Validator { get set }
    var isAbleToProceed: Bool { get set }
}
```

I want to define different types of `Validators` (date of birth validator, email validator, etc.). To do so I created a factory:

```
protocol Validator {}

struct ValidatorFactory {
    internal static let sharedInstance = ValidatorFactory()

    func dateOfBirthValidator(minimumAge: Int, maximumAge: Int) -> DateOfBirthValidator {
        return DateOfBirthValidator(minimumAge: minimumAge, maximumAge: maximumAge)
    }

    func driversLicenseValidator(minLicenseDuration: Int) -> DriversLicenseValidator {
        return DriversLicenseValidator(minLicenseDuration: minLicenseDuration)
    }
}
```

and this is the implementation of DateOfBirthValidator:

```
struct DateOfBirthValidator: Validator {
    let minimumAge: Int
    let maximumAge: Int

    func isDateOfBirthValid(date: Date) -> Bool {
        if let age = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.year], from: date, to: Date()).year {
            return (minimumAge ... maximumAge).contains(age)
        } else {
            return false
        }
    }
}
```

Then I would have a class, ViewController, implementing the Validatable protocol:

```
class ViewController: Validatable {

    // MARK: Internal Properties

    internal var validator: DriversLicenseValidator
    internal var isAbleToProceed: Bool = false

}
```

> But the compiler would report that ViewController does not conform to `Validatable` (does not have a Validator)

This can be solve if I make `Validator` a superclass and all the validators structs turn into classes and inherit from it. But is there a way to make it work with structs and protocols?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42561685/why-cant-a-get-only-property-requirement-in-a-protocol-be-satisfied-by-a-proper) is almost a duplicate of yours, except that it asks why a get-only property can't be satisfied through protocol conformance. The answer there is that, in theory it could, but right now you can't.  There are a couple of Swift bugs on this

- [A generic bug](https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-522) that covers variations on this issue and
- [A specific bug](https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-1950) which is almost exactly your question and was closed as a duplicate of the first.

Now, in your case you have a get/set property (at least as it is declared in the protocol; you made it `let` in your implementation).

Because of the Liskov Subsitution Principle I should be able to say:

```
var someValidatable = ViewController() as Validatable
someValidateable.validator = SocialSecurityValidator()
```

If you were able to do what you want, this would fail for two reasons:

1. `validator` has a more restricted access and is `let` instead of `var`
2. A `SocialSecurityValidator` can't be assigned to `validator` because it is of type `DriversLicenseValidator`