# Why doesn't Swift consider protocol adopter properties to be conformant?

Tags: swift

```
protocol Animal {}
struct Lion: Animal {}
protocol Zoo {
    var animals: [Animal] { get }
}
struct BronxZoo: Zoo { // error: Type 'BronxZoo' does not conform to protocol 'Zoo'
    var animals: [Lion] = []
}
```

If `BronxZoo` has an `animals` array of type `Lion`, which conforms to `Animal`, then why isn't `BronxZoo` considered to be in conformance with `Zoo`?

Comment: This has _nothing_ to do with "subprotocol properties".

Comment: This is essentially a duplicate of [Why can't a get-only property requirement in a protocol be satisfied by a property which conforms?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42561685/2976878), just with arrays – it's something that Swift should arguably be able to support, but it currently doesn't. You can use the same workarounds given in the linked Q&A, either define a 'dummy' forwarding property, or introduce an associated type.

Comment: No, it's not a duplicate. This question assumes that Swift arrays are covariant. The answer should correct that (invalid) assumption, and the question you linked to doesn't do so.

Comment: @robmayoff Swift arrays are covariant – a `[Lion]` can be converted to an `[Animal]`.

Comment: @Hamish If you're going to edit the question you should eliminate OutdoorZoo; it is a red herring.

Comment: I stand corrected.