# What does `override` mean in a protocol?

Tags: swift, overriding, swift-protocols

I've seen this odd thing in the standard library for things like [some](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/floatingpoint/2884257) [operators](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/floatingpoint/2884273) [for](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/floatingpoint/2886135) [`FloatingPoint`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/floatingpoint) ([full source code](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/stdlib/public/core/FloatingPoint.swift)).

```swift
protocol Foo: Bar {
    override static func baz()
}
```

I know that this is necessary when overriding some superclass' open method... but I've never needed to do this in a protocol, nor do I know what it means.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means the protocol declares a new member that replaces an identical member in a parent protocol, though this isn't the same thing as "shadowing" (so it isn't exactly like C#'s `new` method-modifier keyword, also Swift supports `static` protocols, something C#s `interface` can't do).

In the link you gave for `public protocol FloatingPoint`, we see that `FloatingPoint` implements `SignedNumeric`.

`FloatingPoint` declares `override mutating func negate()` - but so does `SignedNumeric` - hence the need to add `override`.

The official Swift language 5.1 reference states this about the `override` keyword on classes (but not explicitly protocols), but the preface of the section implies that it applies to protocols insofar as it applies to *all* declarations:

> https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/ReferenceManual/Declarations.html#ID473
>
> Methods that override a superclass method must be marked with the `override` declaration modifier. It’s a compile-time error to override a method without the `override` modifier or to use the `override` modifier on a method that doesn’t override a superclass method.

Comment: What's the usefulness of this? I thought simply declaring protocol inheritance also inherited the parent protocol's requirements

Comment: @KyLeggiero (I'm not up-to-date on Swift, but I assume it's for future-proofing for when they do eventually support return-type-covariance (as of 2017, [it wasn't supported](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42561685/why-cant-a-get-only-property-requirement-in-a-protocol-be-satisfied-by-a-proper)) - another reason is if you want to somehow extend the original protocol's declaration, such as adding `@attributes` - or updating the inline documentation.

Comment: Thank you! Those are really great reasons that make a lot of sense