# Does Swift support covariance-return-type in protocols?

Tags: swift, protocols, covariance, covariant-return-types

I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57385250/what-does-override-mean-in-a-protocol) that function overriding is available in protocols. Obviously, it can be overriding of signature, not of implementation. So, if it isn't shadowing, it makes sense only for covariance/contravariance. I tried to test it and my check failed.

```
class Egg { }

class EasterEgg : Egg { }

protocol EggTray {
  func get_1() -> Egg;
  func get_2() -> Egg;
  func get_3() -> Egg;
  func get_4() -> Egg;
}

protocol EasterEggTray : EggTray { 
  override func get_1() -> EasterEgg;
  override func get_2() -> EasterEgg;
  override func get_3() -> EasterEgg;
  override func get_4() -> EasterEgg;
}
```

The error message says that 'override' is supported but the compiler can't match two functions (It ignores covariance).

> error: method does not override any method from its parent protocol
> override func get_1() -> EasterEgg;

> note: potential overridden instance method 'get_1()' here
> func get_1() -> Egg;

Covariance-return-type works for classes, but for protocols, it isn't compilable. Does Swift support covariance-return-type in protocols? If yes - How does Swift expect it to be written in code? (I know how  to do it with the associated type, but it isn't what I am looking for.) If not - Why not? What is the reason why Swift doesn't support it? What is the reason for the 'override' keyword in protocols?

Comment: Did you see [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57385250/what-does-override-mean-in-a-protocol#comment121530447_57385340)? That should answer your question. See also [SR-522](https://github.com/apple/swift/issues/43139). Protocol covariant return is probably planned, but no one has got around to doing it yet.

Comment: In this case you create a new method signature as the return type is not the same (it’s a subclass of protocol return type)

Comment: Not only that but if you have a type that conforms to `EggTray` but you have functions with signatures of the form `func get_x() -> EasterEgg` you will get an error because the compiler doesn't consider that to meet the requirement to have a function of the form `func get_x() -> Egg`