# Swift protocol conformance issue

Tags: ios, swift, protocols

I have 2 protocols and a class that conforms to it.

```swift
protocol SomeProtocol: AnyObject { }

protocol AnotherProtocol: AnyObject { }

protocol HelperProtocol {
  var delegate: AnotherProtocol? { get }
}

class SomeClass {
  weak var delegate: (SomeProtocol & AnotherProtocol)?
}

extension SomeClass: HelperProtocol { // Type 'SomeClass' does not conform to protocol 'HelperProtocol'

}
```

How do I fix the compile error?

Comment: Try replacing ```var delegate: AnotherProtocol?``` to ```var delegate: (SomeProtocol & AnotherProtocol)?```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no fundamental reason why Swift *can't* support this, but it just doesn't (as of now).  [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42716340/704319) does a good job explaining.

The best solution I think, while unfortunately ugly, is to make two properties.

```
class SomeClass: HelperProtocol {
  weak var strictlyTypedDelegate: (SomeProtocol & AnotherProtocol)?
  var delegate: AnotherProtocol? { strictlyTypedDelegate }
}
```