# Why the protocol cannot be inherited

Tags: swift, swift-protocols

Here is my code:

```
protocol base{}

protocol sub: base{}

protocol SomeProtocol{
    var a: base{get}
}

struct SomeStruct: SomeProtocol{
//    var a: base
    var a: sub
}
```

when I use `var a: sub` in Struct, I get an error:

> Type 'SomeStruct' does not conform to protocol 'SomeProtocol'

I'm wondering `var a: sub` should conform to base protocol, but why Swift cannot write like this? Is there any better plan?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[The problem with conforming types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42561685/why-cant-a-get-only-property-requirement-in-a-protocol-be-satisfied-by-a-proper) applies to derived protocols as well. Workarounds, listed there, look like this for your code:

```swift
protocol SomeProtocol {
  associatedtype A: Base
  var a: A { get }
}

struct SomeStruct<A: Sub>: SomeProtocol {
  var a: A
}
```

```swift
protocol SomeProtocol {
  var a: any Base { get }
}

struct SomeStruct: SomeProtocol {
  var _a: any Sub
  var a: any Base { _a }
}
```